# Cart Throb Sales price have an expiry date

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce

Has anyone ever been able to have a product on sale in CartThrob for a set period of time?  What I want is to have certain products on sale for a set period of time and then it automatically goes back to regular price after a set date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to use Discounts (as opposed to Coupon Codes) to do this. Discounts are just regular entries so you can set an expiry date on them.

Discounts are applied at checkout without the need for the customer to enter any code. You can set up various types of discount based on products, prices, quantities etc. using the built in methods. It's also possible to create custom discount plugins if you have any specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks that may be an option.  Although when I display the product I want show the sale price (after discount) Unless I manually go in and remove the sale price from the product entry the sale price cannot expire.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I *think* it's possible to use the discount entries in that way to modify a price shown. An alternate solution would be to use a Matrix/Grid to set a price and date. Then use template logic to show the appropriate price (and feed into the add_to_cart form).

Comment: Actually, you don't need a matrix/grid. Just 2 extra fields for "sale price" and "sale end date".

Comment: do I need a new sales price field or can I use the existing one?  I just need a new date field to use as a condition to control the sales price?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. Have a sale price field and an extra date field to say when the sale ends (you could expand it with a sale starts field too). Taking it further, you could set the sale dates as global variables and use them to turn on/off the sale for many items at once. I haven't tried this method but it sounds feasible.